# how to change this regular expression to make it functional

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to do a check on a textBox is an amount to be of the form ***.xxx**

```
if( mnt == null || !mnt.matches("^\\d*$.\\d{3}") ){
   //bla-bla-bla
}
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: Move your `$` to very end of regex and remove `*` and replace it by `+`. If I am not mistaking then it will work without `^` (start)  and `$` (end) of string regex,

Comment: One more thing your `if` condition why it is so weird?

Comment: @Smit without `$` the expression would yield false positive, e.g with `123.xxxwhatever`. The `^` is not necessary though, unless OP wants to check strictly the first part of the filename (which may be the case).

Comment: @GaborSch I dont think its needed. OP is matching against whole string and not to the part of it.

Comment: @Smit You are right, I couldn't check, but according to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) `matches` work just like if `^` and `$` were always present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `^\\d*\\.\\d{3}$`?

Put `$` to the end, and use escape to the `.` character.